# How can I split a view into x number of columns?

Tags: obiee

I have a view in OBIEE that is sectioned and returning groups as intended. My question though, is can I make the sections return in more than 1 column? Right now there are 8 sections all in a long line. I would prefer to split them into two columns of 4 sections each, in the same view.

Is this possible?

THanks

*It will be used in a dashboard at some point.

Comment: This analysis that has 8 sections on it, are you creating it for use with a dashboard, or just as an ad hoc report?

Comment: Yes, it will be used in a dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this will be used on a dashboard, you could consider using a compound layout.

The compound layout button is on the results page in the toolbar. Click on it, name it to something that will help you identify it later, then break your data apart into two sections (using filters, creating two different tables within the same report, or some other means. This is the part where I don't know your data or its format so it makes it difficult to answer). One section of data will go on one compound layout, and another section will go on the other compound layout. So in the report, the data will be on two *tabs*, but since it is intended for a dashboard, this is not a problem.

Make two side by side columns on the dashboard, and drag the same report into both. In the properties, select "show View", and select the different compound views (one for each column).

Now when you run the dash, the results will display in different columns at the same time.